# How should a scheme recursive function return the binding with the specified name in the closest environment

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm trying to write a scheme  recursive function (lookup-env name environment), which returns the binding (pair) with the specified name in an environment (i.e. list of association lists) and null if no such binding is found.

```
(define (lookup name assoc_list) 
  (cond
    ((null? assoc_list) '())
    ((equal? name (caar assoc_list)) (car assoc_list))
   (else (lookup name (cdr assoc_list)))))


(define (lookup-env name environment) 
  (cond
   ((null? environment) '())
   ((equal? name (car (lookup name environment))) (lookup name environment))
   (else (lookup name (cdr environment)))))
```

I should be able to test it out like this

```
(define l1 '( (ben "short") (cara "walking") (dan "bald")))
(define l2 '( (kurt "is not") (ski "skinny") (kim "cook") (cara "injured")))

(define e (list l1 l2) )

(lookup-env 'ben e)
;Value 14: (ben "short")

(lookup-env 'kurt e)
;Value 15: (kurt "is not")

(lookup-env 'cara e)
;Value 16: (cara "walking")

(lookup-env 'jaga e)
;Value 17: ()
```

however when i try it i get the error

```
;The object (), passed as the first argument to car, is not the correct type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871463/looking-up-pairing-lists-in-scheme). Assuming that the `lookup` procedure is correctly implemented, there's a mistake in the second condition of the posted code (this was causing the error, when you tried to take the `car` of an empty list); also in the last case the recursive call is incorrect, you're invoking the wrong procedure. Try this instead:

```
(define (lookup-env name environment)
  (cond
    ((null? environment) '())
    ((not (null? (lookup name (car environment))))
     (lookup name (car environment)))
    (else (lookup-env name (cdr environment)))))
```

But we can do a bit better, and avoid doing a double `lookup` in the second condition:

```
(define (lookup-env name environment)
  (if (null? environment)
      '()
      (let ((binding (lookup name (car environment))))
        (if (not (null? binding))
            binding
            (lookup-env name (cdr environment))))))
```

Comment: sorry i thought car '() returns '()

Comment: @LokiKira Thats true for CL, not for Scheme.

Comment: @LokiKira is as Sylwester says, it doesn't work like that in Scheme. In fact, to make things easier in Scheme it'd be better if `lookup` returned `#f` when the binding isn't found. As it currently is, it adds a little hassle testing whether the binding was found or not